# blueprint equivalent of util:list from Spring

Tags: blueprint-osgi

I tried to look through the websites and documents but I cannot find blueprint equivalent of util:list from Spring? Did I overlook something? if is not there, what would be the alternative? In either case, I need a list of beans injected into another bean - was planning to use util:list but..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
<bean id="myList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <argument>
        <list value-type="com.example.MyType">
            <ref component-id="mycomponent1"/>
            <ref component-id="mycomponent2"/>
            <ref component-id="mycomponent3"/>
            <bean class="com.example.MySubType"/>
        </list>
    </argument>
</bean>
```

ArrayList takes a Collection as constructor argument (as does LinkedList btw.). So you just create a bean of type List and provide the list of bean references or beans in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a list-element in the http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd namespace.

> The set of "value" types that can be used in any place a value
>                   can be specified.  This set includes the < ref > and < idref > elements, any of the
>                   component types (< bean >, < service >, etc.) as inline components, the
>                   generic  element for types sourced from string values, any of the
>                   collection types (< set >, < list >, < array >, < map >, < props >), and the
>                   < null > type to inject a null value.

Also, you can find an example here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.sample/0.4/OSGI-INF/blueprint/config.xml

Comment: I am looking for the equivalent of util:list, not the list that goes as 'value' of properties.